# How can you create a shared secret for IdentityServer4?

Tags: identityserver4, sha, shared-secret

All the documentation and examples I've seen all use C# code to generate the secret, like this:

```cs
new Secret("secret".Sha256())
```

This is fine for an initial setup and inserting into the database on startup, but what if I want to add a secret directly to the database at run time. Preferably I'd like to give instructions to a customer that doesn't involve any code.

I've tried using online tools to hash the string then Base64 encode the string but it's not matching what the code generates so I think I'm missing a step.

Answer (score 4):

The code for that function is here:

https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/blob/master/src/IdentityServer4/src/Extensions/HashExtensions.cs

You could create a tool or library of your own that meets your requirements. We have a SQL implementation so we can easily import clients directly into our DB should we need to.

Comment: Is that something you can share? I've tried creating a script myself but it seems that Azure SQL Server uses UTF-16 whereas Identity uses UTF-8, and I can't manage to encode the SQL one to be UTF-8.
Edit: Nevermind, I was using NVARCHAR variables. If I call the HASHBYTES function on the string directly, it works:
`HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', 'MySecret' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8)`